# How to open a BLOB file from MySQL using Python without saving?

Tags: python, mysql

**Code:**

```
import mysql.connector
import sys

def write_file(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)

sampleNum = 0;
db_config = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='test',
                      host='localhost',
                      database='technical')
# query blob data form the authors table
cursor = db_config.cursor()

try:
    sampleNum=sampleNum+1;
    query = "SELECT fileAttachment FROM document_control WHERE id=%s"
    cursor.execute(query,(sampleNum,))
    file = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    write_file(file, 'User'+str(sampleNum)+'.docx')


except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

**What it does**

The above code - gets the file from MySQL stored as a `BLOB` and it saves me a `.docx` file into a folder.

**Question**

But instead of saving it, view it then delete it. Am I able to simply open the `BLOB` in word without saving it?

If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, passing binary data like a `BLOB` entity as a file-like object can be done with the built-in module `io`, for example:

```py
import io

f = io.BytesIO(data)
# f now can be used anywhere a file-object is expected
```

But your question actually comes more down to MS Word's ability to open files that aren't saved anywhere on the disk. I don't think it can do that. Best practice would probably be to generate a temporary file using `tempfile`, so that you can at least expect the system to clean it up eventually:

```py
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.docx', delete=False) as f:
    f.write(data)
    print(f.name)
```

**Edit:**

In your code in particular, you could try the following to store the data in a temporary file and automatically open it in MS Word:

```py
import tempfile, subprocess

WINWORD_PATH = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe'

def open_as_temp_docx(data):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.docx', delete=False) as f:
        f.write(data)
    subprocess.Popen([WINWORD_PATH, f.name])
```

```py
cursor = db_config.cursor()

try:
    sampleNum=sampleNum+1;
    query = "SELECT fileAttachment FROM document_control WHERE id=%s"
    cursor.execute(query,(sampleNum,))
    open_as_temp_docx(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

I don't have a Windows machine with MS Word at hand, so I can't test this. The path to `winword.exe` on your machine may vary, so make sure it is correct.

**Edit:**

If it is important to delete the file as soon as MS Word closes, the following should work:

```py
import tempfile, subprocess, os

WINWORD_PATH = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe'

def open_as_temp_docx(data):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.docx', delete=False) as f:
        f.write(data)
    subprocess.Popen([WINWORD_PATH, f.name]).wait()
    if os.path.exists(f.name):
        os.unlink(f.name)
```

Comment: That'll do! with my current code - what would I replace your code with?

Comment: Are you on Windows, Linux or macOS?

Comment: Windows I am currently using

Comment: Hi thanks for this - got Microsoft word error = `Sorry, we couldn't find your file. was it moved, renamed, or deleted? (c:...tmpylcf3leg.docx`

Comment: Oops, `tempfile` by default deletes files as soon as you've finished writing to them. I added `delete=False` above which should make the file persist long enough for Word to open it.

Comment: Perfect! This is very intelligent Seb! - Where did you learn this?

Comment: How can I delete it after? It is stored in `..local/temp/`

Comment: Mainly from googling and reading documentation! For deleting, you could simply wait for the system to do it as the file is in a temporary folder. Otherwise, see my last edit.

Comment: Just been reading that here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile .. thanks for all your time!